# Translate date (output ACF , wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, date, time, advanced-custom-fields

I want to translate the output of a datetime picker of a acf field in Wordpress.

The admin language is dutch but my output need to go in English

`$date = "Okt 13, 2019 16:00:00"; (this is my output from ACF)`

this is what I want

`$date = "Oct 13, 2019 16:00:00"; (the month is now in English format)`

Is there a way to do date, without changing the admin language or changing the acf field.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/231498 you can try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a translation table that corrects the differences between the months from Dutch to English.

```
$input = "Okt 13, 2019 16:00:00"; //from ACF
$translate = ['Mrt' => 'Mar', 'Mei' => 'May', 'Okt' => 'Oct'];  //check it!
$date = strtr($input, $translate);
echo $date;  //Oct 13, 2019 16:00:00
```